# '-batch' in openssl

Tags: openssl

I came across the following command today and I'm not sure what the `'-batch'` does.

```
openssl req -new -key  /usr/RDB/keyfolder/${SITE}-new.key -out /usr/RDB/certfolder/${SITE}.csr -config ${SITE}.conf -batch
```

Answer (score 2):

[`man openssl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/openssl) will take you to [`man req`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/req). In there is the explanation for `-batch`

> -batch
>     non-interactive mode.